# omitting "s" in subjunctive mood

Tags: subjunctives, mandative

> 1.Etiquette requires that the bride's father make**s** a speech.
>
> 2.The situation requires that he go there.

***UPDATED: These are two different sentences. My questions are about those, not only one of them. No one has explained anything as to the latter.***

I am wondering the reason for--in the first sentence -- there has been used the ***s*** on *make**s***.

Basically, I meant although the two sentences are subjunctive, in fact, why the first one has used ***s***.

Comment: You've already asked a [similar question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30872/different-uses-of-subjunctive) before. The answer I've given there should also be sufficient for this thread too. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first sentence, **makes** is actually in the indicative mood, not the subjunctive. That’s why **makes** has an **s**.

In the second sentence, **go** is in the subjunctive mood. That’s why it’s not **goes**.

Regarding the *meaning* of the sentences, both verbs describe a required situation that may or may not actually occur. The first sentence doesn't say that the bride's father *is* making a speech or *will* make a speech; it only says that he is required to. This is what calls for the subjunctive mood. When the wedding really happens, maybe the bride's father will do what etiquette requires of him, and maybe he won't.

However, *grammatically,* the subjunctive mood is mostly optional in English. People usually usually put the verb governed by **require** into the subjunctive mood, but not always. In other words, these sentences mean the same as your examples:

> Etiquette requires that the bride's father **make** a speech.
>
> The situation requires that he **goes** there.

Comment: The first sentence since it does have the "s" might be said to be grammatically in the indicative mood, but semantically it is a subjunctive clause and thus, historically would have used the subjunctive form of the verb.

Comment: Ben, what do you mean by "real"??

Comment: And, could we say just"goes" instead of "go"?

Comment: @nima By "may or may not be real", I meant that the requirement may or may not be fulfilled. So, the subordinate clause isn't describing the real world as it is, it's describing a sort of imagined world of what is required. I'll edit the answer to use a clearer word than "real".

Comment: @nima Regarding "goes", yes, you can say "go" or "goes". This is what I mean by the subjunctive mood being optional. If you say "...requires that he **goes**...", that's indicative. If you say "...requires that he **go**...", that's subjunctive. The meaning is the same in both cases. Copperkettle's answer provides some sentences where the meaning changes, but those are unusual. The subjunctive mood has been dying out for over 100 years, and is almost forgotten, but people do still use it frequently, especially in the United States.

Comment: Great. Now I can get all the explanations and get my answer very well.

Answer (score 3):

Ben Kovitz is right: it's not a crime to use the indicative mood, people will still understand what you meant to say.

There are rare instances when the meanings will be different:

> 1. I insist that the bride's father **makes** a speech. (indicative:  I am sure that the ceremony calls for the bride’s father to make a speech.)
> 2. I insist that the bride's father **make** a speech. (subjunctive: I want the bride's father to deliver his speech, and I want it very much - I express my desire)
> 3. The bride was insistent that her father **made** a speech. (indicative: She assured someone that her father made a speech)
> 4. The bride was insistent that her father **make** a speech (subjunctive: She wanted her father to deliver a speech).

This is described quite well in Wikipedia's article on [Subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_present_subjunctive). The article says that British speakers of English more often use the indicative form (1, 3) in informal speech.

Comment: That's because most Brits wouldn't know the difference between the two [& that includes me, unless it is shown as these examples] & would be most unlikely to use the subjunctive in everyday usage.  ;)

Comment: Actually, using the indicative when the meaning is subjunctive _is_ a crime, but England is a land of scofflaws.

Comment: Seriously, I like the list of situations where the choice of mood affects the meaning. However, the situation you described with “makes a speech” actually calls for the presnt progressive, not the simple present tense. However, the indicative meaning could be something like: I am sure that the ceremony calls for the bride’s father to make a speech. (There I go with the subjunctive again to explain it, though.)

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @BenKovitz! I used your definition in the answer.