# It was advised that ____ inside until the storm passed our area

Tags: subjunctives

> Choose the word or set of words that, when inserted in the sentence, best fits the meaning of the sentence as a whole
>
> It was advised that ____ inside until the storm passed our area.
>
> 1) we are staying
>
> 2) we stay
>
> 3) we may
>
> 4) we stayed

I believe that the answer is 2. But, I also think 4 is equally correct because I know most subjunctive structures can be replaced by "should + infinitive" or ordinary present and past tenses. Am I right?

Comment: Pedants will say that only #2 (the subjunctive usage) is correct in such contexts. But in practice, as pointed out by [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/47002/126) to an earlier question, native speakers today increasingly use the "indicative" (tensed) form as per your example #4. So it really depends what you mean by "correct" (what do native speakers actually *say*, as opposed to what do examiners expect you to give as the correct answer?).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I must be pedantic, but to me only 2) is OK. If you consider the time when the "advisory" was made, it would say something like "*stay* inside until ...".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank heaven for an example in which the subjunctive is not only correct, but best! I reckon No. 2 must "sound right" to even the most dedicated hater, and "It was advised that we stayed" sounds like the mish-mash it is. Rather than close-vote this question, I propose that it be bronzed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers One problem with this question is that today's native speakers will seldom begin a sentence with _"It was advised that..."_, thus avoiding the issue of what might follow. Instead, we might hear the dummy subject, e.g.: _"They advised us (to stay)..."_

Comment: @P. E. Dant: In that case the example might just as well have contrasted *They advised that we **stayed** indoors* with *They advised that we **stay** indoors*. Switching from passive to active voice doesn't affect the specific (subjunctive) usage being queried.