# "it's truly vital that he or she becomes/become familiar with the reasons"?

Tags: subjunctives, mandative

Please have a look at sentence below:

> Before one votes on the proposition, it's truly vital that he or she **becomes/become** familiar with the reasons for voting both for the proposition and against the proposition.

Does it have any grammar issue?

My book says, "become familiar", "proposal". Do you agree with the book?

Comment: You shouldn't be "accepting" an answer post so quickly. Because you have, you've potentially discouraged other members from providing you more info, and what might be better info, for your question.

Comment: OK. What's your answer?

Comment: Both "become" and "becomes" are acceptable: the first uses a subjunctive mandative construction, the second uses the covert mandative construction. Here's some more info related to mandative constructions: [Different uses of subjunctive](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/31376/8758).

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with calling it a "proposition". Ballot issues (in AmE) can be called "propositions".  However, the sentence seems to be speaking of only one of them, so I would suggest consistent use of the singular "proposition".

As for "become", the book is correct—but this is not the conjugated third-person-plural "become", it is the subjunctive "become".

- (important that) {whoever} become

The only other thing that is syntactically odd is the placement of "both".  One needs to be aware of reasons for voting for, or against, the proposition, but most localities won't let you VOTE "both for and against" it, no matter how good your reasons!

- ...the reasons, both for voting for the proposition and for voting against {it/the proposition}.

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock. 'Become' is not the bare infinitive; it's the present subjunctive.

Comment: All agree that _becomes_ is not correct and it should be _become_?

Comment: Yes. I was wrong about why, but at least Tunny and I agree it should be "become".